# Bind 9 + SQL DB (Best way)

Tags: domain-name-system, sql, bind

I'm going to be getting back into running a TLD, I've been out of the loop for a few years. I was originally considering running PowerDNS, which is great, but my backup NS host insists we run bind due to the strong DNSSEC. I've looked at things like SDB, but most of the solutions seem ancient, and I doubt they would even successfully patch Bind 9. What in your opinion is the way to get SQL (preferably MySQL) support into bind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, We're migrating from MyDNS for a nearly identical reason

Comment: I am certainly interested in reports on the use of a SQL backend with DNSSEC...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What specific benefits of using a SQL back-end are you aiming for?

- instant real-time updates?
- integration with provisioning systems?
- something else?

If the aim is ultimately to get DNSSEC support then those two benefits may not be relevant.  As far as I know (although I could be wrong) none of the DB backends to BIND will support DNSSEC nicely.

However many of the benefits above can also be achieved using dynamic updates (i.e. sending DNS messages which alter the zone file on the fly).  Alternatively, if it's not necessary to publish new records the instant they're registered just script an export from SQL which generates the file in native BIND format and signs it at the same time.

Various TLDs are already using (or preparing to use) various combinations of the above.

Comment: I mainly prefer sql due to the ease of integration with our site, but realtime updates are not necessary. So I will go with your last suggestion, thanks.

Comment: DynDB supports DNSSEC but as you say DLZ does not, currently there is no SQL backed DynDB provider library. (only LDAP SFAIK)

Answer (score 2):

DLZ (various backends including LDAP, serious databases like PostgreSQL, and MySQL) is integrated into BIND for a few versions (9.3 ?). So, you no longer need to patch BIND.

Otherwise, see the excellent warnings by Alnitak.